# Empty Result Set JDBC On Oracle Call

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle, jdbc

For some reason I am getting an empty result set back when my database has records stored in it. Does anyone see anything off about my code? I am using JDBC and Java for it. If someone could point me to the right direction that would be wonderful. Thank you.

```
List<Person> login_account = new ArrayList<Person>();
Connection conn = cf.getConnection();
Statement stmt;
stmt = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs;
rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT USERNAME, PASSWORD, ACCOUNT_LEVEL FROM BANKING_ACCOUNTS");
Person person = null;

while (rs.next()) {
    person = new Person( rs.getString("USERNAME"), rs.getString("PASSWORD"), rs.getString("ACCOUNT_LEVEL"));
    login_account.add(person);
}
```

Here is the person class:

```
public Person(String username, String password, String account_level) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.account_level = account_level;
}
```

Here is the sql associated to it:

```
  CREATE TABLE "JONATHANWISNIEWSKI"."BANKING_ACCOUNTS" 
 (  "USER_ID" NUMBER(15,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
 "FIRST_NAME" VARCHAR2(15 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
 "LAST_NAME" VARCHAR2(25 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
 "ADDRESS" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
 "CITY" VARCHAR2(25 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
 "STATE" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
 "ZIPCODE" VARCHAR2(5 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
 "USERNAME" VARCHAR2(15 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
 "PASSWORD" VARCHAR2(15 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
 "PHONE" VARCHAR2(10 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
 "SSN" VARCHAR2(9 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
 "ACCOUNT_LEVEL" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
 "BANK_ACCOUNT_ID" NUMBER(15,0) NOT NULL ENABLE
 ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
 PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
 STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
TABLESPACE "USERS" ;

 CREATE OR REPLACE EDITIONABLE TRIGGER "JONATHANWISNIEWSKI"."USER_ID_BIR" 
 BEFORE INSERT ON BANKING_ACCOUNTS 
 FOR EACH ROW

 BEGIN
 SELECT USER_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL
 INTO   :new.USER_ID
 FROM   dual;
 END;

 /
 ALTER TRIGGER "JONATHANWISNIEWSKI"."USER_ID_BIR" ENABLE;

 CREATE OR REPLACE EDITIONABLE TRIGGER "      
 JONATHANWISNIEWSKI"."BANK_ACCOUNT_ID_BIR" 
 BEFORE INSERT ON BANKING_ACCOUNTS 
 FOR EACH ROW

 BEGIN
 SELECT BANK_ACCOUNT_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL
 INTO   :new.BANK_ACCOUNT_ID
 FROM   dual;
 END;

 /
ALTER TRIGGER "JONATHANWISNIEWSKI"."BANK_ACCOUNT_ID_BIR" ENABLE;
```

Here is the Sql code attached to itL

Comment: So you ran this in a debugger, and rs.next() never enters the while loop?

Comment: I figured it out. The inserts never comitted